# javax.jms does not exist - compiling activemq examples

Tags: java, netbeans, jms, activemq-classic

I'm trying to compile the examples that come with activemq

in apache-activemq-5.1.0\example\src\

TopicPublisher.java, CommandLineSupport.java

on compiling thru netbeans it has some referencing problems saying javax.jms does not exist.

I've tried the j2ee.jar, openjms, sun jms but they all give the same error.

its also complaining about org.apache.activemq.util does not exist but I'm referencing activemq-all-5.1.0.jar.

note: all other references to external jars are working fine

any ideas?

**Edit**: the jars needed to be referenced are

```
activemq-core-5.1.0.jar
geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
geronimo-j2ee-management_1.0_spec-1.0.jar
```

they're in the activemq binary dist in the lib folder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the lib directory are the jars you'll need to compile things. The JMS API is inside *lib/geronimo-jms-1.1.jar*.

How are you trying to build them BTW? You using the Ant build that is there? See the [documentation on building them](http://activemq.apache.org/examples.html).

Comment: doh thanks I should've seen that,

I've dropped them into an existing netbeans project and its using Ant to compile. I'll try and sort that out tonight thanks

Comment: The reminder to crack open build.xml for a wealth of information is very helpful. I just hope I remember to do it the next time I'm chasing down undefined type exceptions! :)